# how does firefox store saved passwords?

Tags: firefox

I'm going to create a plug in to face recognition system for firefox saved passwords as my final year project? but yet i haven't any idea about save passwords in firefox. if anybody know about that, Plz help me.

Where does firefox store saved passwords? I guess it's in the firefox profile, but where exactly? Are they encrypted on the disk? With which keys? Is that method different depending of the OS?

Comment: You should make a Chrome plugin instead :D

Answer (score 0):

The first time you visit a website and enter credentials (ie. username/email and password), Firefox will ask if you would like to save the credentials with the options similar to: Remember, Not Now, and Never for This Site.

Are you trying to add face recognition as a stored credential (as a supplement to saved password)?

Comment: thanks dear.. bt I asked the background method of saving passwords in firefox. i'm going to add face recognition to saved passwords. then only password owner can use passwords.

Comment: I apologize for misunderstanding. Thanks for clarifying.