# Where does Firefox store saved passwords?

Tags: firefox, passwords

I'm going to create a plugin to a face recognition system for Firefox's saved passwords as my final year project, but yet i haven't any idea about how saved passwords are implemented in Firefox. if anybody know about that, Please help me.

Where does Firefox store saved passwords? How does it choose appropriate password when entering username?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how does firefox store saved passwords?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8731740/how-does-firefox-store-saved-passwords)

Answer (score 2):

You can find your saved passwords by going to:

> Firefox --> Options --> Security

and click Saved Passwords. Your passwords are ordered by site. You'll get a list of all usernames, and you have to click Show Passwords to actually be able to see your passwords. I suggest using a master password (you can set this in the security tab) so no one else can access your passwords.

Comment: thanx, when we use master password it protect only password details. what happen if anybody come and enter your username??

Comment: Well, they can still log in on your computer and do wrong from there, but that's the downside of letting your browser saving your passwords. I do however believe that with a master password you have to enter the masterpassword before it will auto-fill login details for you (at browser startup).

Off course, the safest thing is not to save your passwords, unless you know no one else will en up on your pc without you being around.

Answer (score 0):

i think you mean 'where in the file system does firefox store passwords'

on linux, firefox has a hidden folder on your home folder (usually .mozilla) there are a couple folders in the folder and in one of the folders there exists a file with the name 'logins.json'