# Where in the filesystem does Firefox store saved passwords?

Tags: firefox, passwords

You probably think this is a duplicate of [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8732052/where-does-firefox-store-saved-passwords) It's not,  because that question has never been sufficiently answered.

Where does Firefox store passwords? It must be in a directory somewhere, right?

My best guess would be (on Linux) somewhere in /home/user/.mozilla/someprofile.default/...

I would greatly appreciate it, if someone could finally answer this question.

Comment: What an odd piece of deduction. That the original question doesn't have a 'sufficient' answer doesn't make this any less of a duplicate!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where does Firefox store saved passwords?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8732052/where-does-firefox-store-saved-passwords)

Comment: @Stewart_R if you look at the flagging text below "a duplicate" you will notice that it says: _"This question has been asked before **and already has an answer**."_

Comment: This may help if you use Linux OS. ..
[Click Here !! ..](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82597/where-does-firefox-store-its-cookies-on-linux)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not a programming related question. But the steps are as follow:

> 1. Open your profile folder:
>
>    Click the menu button (three horizontal bars), click help  and select
>      **Troubleshooting Information**. The Troubleshooting Information tab will
>      open.
> 2. Under the Application Basics section, click on Show Folder. A window with your profile files will open.
>
> **Passwords**
>
> Your passwords are stored in two different files, both of which are
>   required:
>
> key3.db - This file stores your key database for your passwords. To
>   transfer saved passwords, you must copy this file along with the
>   following file.
>
> logins.json - Saved passwords.
>
> For more information
>   see [Password Manager - Remember, delete, change and import saved
>   passwords in Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/password-manager-remember-delete-change-and-import).

Got them from this Mozilla support post:

[Recovering important data from an old profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/recovering-important-data-from-an-old-profile)

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you very much.